# R - Post hoc comparisons in 2x2 ANOVA unequal sample sizes

Tags: r, anova, standard-error, post-hoc

I have a 2x2 between-subject design with (slightly) unequal cell sizes. Hence I chose to use the `anova(lm(...))` function so that Type 1 SS are used:

`anova(lm(prob ~ utility * imagination, data = e2data))`

`prob`is the numerical DV and `utility` and `imagination` are factors with 2 levels each. The ANOVA yields **no significant main or interaction effects**.

Then, I went on to visualise the cell means including errorbars:

```
library(reshape)
mystats <- function(x) round(c(M = mean(x), SD = sd(x), n = length(x), SE = sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))), 2)
prob.means1 <- data.frame(cast(e2data, utility + imagination ~ ., value="prob", mystats))
```

`mystats` calculates the mean, standard deviation, number of observations and standard error of the mean. This results in the following data.frame, which is the basis for the plot below:

```
> prob.means1
  utility imagination    M   SD   n   SE
1    gain      absent 7.18 1.23 100 0.12
2    gain     present 7.49 1.34  95 0.14
3    loss      absent 7.10 1.47 103 0.14
4    loss     present 7.19 1.49  95 0.15
```

The plot:

```
(plot1 <- ggplot(prob.means1, aes(x = utility, y = M,
                                  group = imagination,
                                  color = imagination)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3.5) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=M+SE, ymin=M-SE, width=0.05)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Probability estimate", limits=c(6,8))
)
```

Note that I set the errorbars to range from M-SE to M+SE.

[image: 2x2 plot]

**In the gain condition (left part of the plot) the error bars do not overlap. Does this allow the conclusion that the difference between these two cells is significant? How do I run this post-hoc comparison appropriately (between-subject, unequal sample sizes)?** I tried `Tukey.HSD()` but it doesn't work on a `lm` object. Also, I tried to use `pairwise.t.test` but I couldn't figure out how to use it with more than 1 factor.